# Http Client Timeout after 2 requests

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am experiencing some weird behaviour which i cannot explain. 
For my use case i use awaitility and httpRequests to check whether a service is already deployed or not. OpenShift returns 503 if the service is not ready yet, 200 otherwise.
After 2 requests (which receive 503) the normal behavior turns into timeouts. Manual request still receive 503 and 200 after around 2 minutes.

22-05-2020 11:56:33.448 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[32] - Sending request: GET https://serviceurl HTTP/1.1

22-05-2020 11:56:33.646 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[34] - Receiving 503

22-05-2020 11:56:43.987 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[32] - Sending request: GET https://serviceurl HTTP/1.1

22-05-2020 11:56:43.992 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[34] - Receiving 503

22-05-2020 11:56:54.071 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[32] - Sending request: GET https://serviceurl HTTP/1.1

--> TIMEOUT

```
public void send(HttpUriRequest request) {
    log.info("Sending request (retry for 10m): {}", request);
    await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .pollInterval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoreExceptions()
            .until(() -> client.execute(request), ResponseChecker::is2xxOrRedirectResponse);
}
```

In order to eliminate some potential causes I have rewritten the logic with a simple for loop, sleep and extended logging and used a some external url which is accessible from everywhere.

```
public void send(HttpUriRequest request) {

    for(int i=1;60>=i;i++){
        try {
            log.info("Sending request: {}", request);
                HttpResponse res = client.execute(request);
                log.info("Receiving {}", res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                }catch(InterruptedException edf){
                    System.out.println("Thread was interrupted!");
                }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

22-05-2020 14:56:33.448 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[32] - Sending request: GET https://www.google.de HTTP/1.1

22-05-2020 14:56:33.686 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[34] - Receiving 200

22-05-2020 14:56:43.687 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[32] - Sending request: GET https://www.google.de HTTP/1.1

22-05-2020 14:56:43.770 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[34] - Receiving 200

22-05-2020 14:56:53.771 INFO  RetryingHttpClient.send[32] - Sending request: GET https://www.google.de HTTP/1.1

--> TIMEOUT

If you have any ideas, what the potential causes could be i would be more than happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is leaking connections. Close responses.

Comment: please accept my edit to your answer, then i will mark your answer as solution :). Thanks very much.

Comment: Please always close the response object with `try-finally` or `try-with-resources`.